# Is foreach guaranteed to iterate in the array order in php?

Tags: php, foreach

When an array is passed to `foreach` is the output order guaranteed to be the same as the input? I know in some languages that the output order is not guaranteed since each element is processed at the same time.

For example, I'm passing a sorted array to `foreach` to write to a file. I want to be sure that the array will be sorted in the output file.

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Answers above, but have a look at array_multisort() in case you ever need to sort the array before doing a foreach loop:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: I came here with the same question after reading php `foreach` doc. It doesn't explicity state that order will remain. I'm not talking about examples neither comments. The only reference is to `reset()` talking about the current element and the next element.

Comment: And me neither. I've just looked at the so called “reference”, and could not see anything stating PHP preserves input order of associative arrays, per specification. Unless there is another more meaningful reference, the question is still unanswered (formally speaking), and it may as much be implementation or version dependant.

Comment: I really wish you had given a code example in your question.

Comment: Indeed. It always stays stuck to the order of creation even if you use numeric indexes. If you do this: `$a = []; $a[ 0 ] = 'zero'; $a[ 2 ] = 'two'; $a[ 1 ] = 'one'; var_export( $a );` you'll see the internal order is `[ 0, 2, 1 ]`. If you do `foreach( $a as $n ){ echo $n . " "; }` you'll see `zero two one`.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Yes ...whatever order you will give to foreach it will iterate in same orders. And in your case `array will be sorted in the output file.`

Answer (score 18):

The relevant reference might not be that of `foreach` or sorting as previously mentionned, but that of array instead.

[Language reference — Arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) says:

> An array in PHP is actually an ordered map.

Answer (score 8):

This is correct, `foreach` will output in same order as the input array .

Answer (score 2):

Yes - the items will be output in the same order they are in within the array.