# How does php's foreach decides the order of iteration, for an array with strings as keys?

Tags: php

Being

```
$array = ["string1"=>1,"astring"=>2,"dstring"=>3]
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
   echo $key;
}
```

In what order will the keys be printed, and why? How does php's foreach decide the order?

Comment: Need more code. What is checked ??

Comment: If I'm not mistaken they should end up in the order they were added. Read between the lines [here](http://nikic.github.io/2014/12/22/PHPs-new-hashtable-implementation.html) (Order of elements subheading, can't deeplink)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is foreach guaranteed to iterate in the array order in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733188/is-foreach-guaranteed-to-iterate-in-the-array-order-in-php)

Comment: yes I think its a duplicate but I never ask something I cannot find with google

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They will be iterated in the same order they are in the array. Most likely in the insertion order (if array_push/array_merge or the [] operator was used). That also holds for keys other than strings.

Comment: This is true.  I am dealing with tons of nested arrays and such and this is how it has always worked for me.  If the order matters, the user can [sort the array](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) before starting the iteration.