# PHP - Is iteration on object ordered?

Tags: php, object, iterator

I know that I can use this to iterate on an object:

```
   foreach ($this as $key => $value) {
       print "$key => $value\n";
   }
```

**Is the order in which the properties are looked over always the same or is it random?** 
I tried it a bit and it seems to always follow the declaration order, as in the exemple from here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php

But I couldn't find any documentation where this is formally specified. 
Can an experimented PHP dev confirm or disconfirm what I found in my trials?

Comment: it would appear the order is the same as that in which the properties are intially defined.

Comment: This looks related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733188/is-foreach-guaranteed-to-iterate-in-the-array-order-in-php

Comment: In [this rather extensive answer about foreach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14854568/2734189), a PHP core developer confirms that object iteration is ordered.